# JS return value only of a specific object

Tags: javascript

I currently have an array of preset objects like so:

```
var productsImages = [
  {sg: ''}, {scamo: ''}, {schar: ''}, {mar: ''}, {tb: ''}, {tg: ''}, {tcamo: ''}, {tcamo: ''}, {tol: ''}, {fb: ''}, {fg: ''},
];
```

Each one of these will have a different value.  They're going to be in a specific order in the array.  I need to return the value of each one for example.

```
productsImages[index]
```

What I'm looking for is something like productsImages[0] == give me just the value not the whole object.  How can achieve this?

Comment: `Object.values(productImages[index]))[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map each object to just its one value first, and then you'll have a plain array of values you can manipulate:

```js
var productsImages = [
  {sg: 'foo'}, {scamo: ''}, {schar: ''}, {mar: ''}, {tb: ''}, {tg: ''}, {tcamo: ''}, {tcamo: ''}, {tol: ''}, {fb: ''}, {fg: ''},
];

const values = productsImages.map(obj => Object.values(obj)[0]);
console.log(values[0]);
```